# Measure spaces and nested sequence intersection

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be any measure space. If $ (A_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ and $ \mu(A_1)< \infty$, prove that

$ \mu( \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$

I feel like I need to somehow use the fact about the measure of the union is the sum if they are disjoint, or perhaps De Morgan’s law, but I’m not too sure how.

Comment: This is a very standard result in measure theory and most likely a duplicate on this site as well. For a proof of this fact, see for example [this](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/continuity-of-measures/).

Comment: Thank you! Couldn’t find this on searching,